# Need to find the relation regarding the regression model but ignoring some points in R

Tags: r

I have

```
count2 <- length(which(apple==2))

count2

relation <- lm(random~fruit+food)

print(relation)

summary(relation)
```

I am trying to find the relation between `fruit` and `food` with `random` but only when apples are equal to two. How would I combine my idea of `count2` with the relation of `lm(random~fruit+food)`

Comment: Hi Kat Kot. We have no idea what these variables are. The `count2` variable doesn't help you here. Maybe you want `lm(random~fruit+food, data = data.frame(random, fruit, food)[apple == 2 ,])` ? But without knowing what your variables look like it's just too hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
dataset<-data.frame(apple = sample(seq(1,5,1),50,replace = TRUE),
                    random = rnorm(50,0,1),
                    food = rnorm(50,0,1))

subset_data <-subset(dataset, apple == 2, select = c(apple, random,food))


relation <- lm(random~fruit+food,data=subset_data)

print(relation)

summary(relation)
```